How to use multiple persistent TCP connection with server using TCPNetClientConnectionFactory as base factory
I want to send 2 payloads for 1 transaction over single persistent connection to server. I tried using cachingClientConnectionFactory and ThreadAffinityClientConnectionFactory. But since those both needs single-use=true, its not fulfilling my purpose. It is creating multiple tcp connections but new connections for each payload. Can you suggest the right approach to achieve this? @Gary Russell
